# duplicate attribute AAPT2 link failed in feature Module in Instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am following google codelab for instant app. After I convert the original app to baseFeature and added another feature module which will then act like the application but will be based on the original baseFeature.

As per told in code lab, I changed the buld.gradle files and deleted the application component from the feature Module (Non Base module). When I try to build the project I get the follow error.

```
Error:(4) duplicate attribute
Error:/home/adventure/Desktop/android-topeka/topekaapk/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:4 duplicate attribute
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':topekaapk:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: It is fixed now, I have tested with Android Studio RC1. you can test with Android Studio RC1 and newer Android studio.

Comment: error was reported at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63736468 and now it has been fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got stabbed in my back by lint , **YES LINT**

[image]

**Problem :** As shown in the image **Lint gave an warning** for optimizing the import and I removed the xmlns property from manifest.

**Solution :** Do not delete the xmlns property